# Windows 7, Netbeans and svn

Tags: svn, netbeans

I used to use Eclipse as IDE for Java programming. Since all my Java projects are located at SVN server, i have used "Subclipse" plugin to access my code. I works fine.
Recently i have decided to switch to Netbeans (faster, more agile, cleaner interface). It has built-in support for SVN, BUT... when i enter my svn credentials (same link, same username and pass as with Subclipse) i can't checkout any project! I get this error message:

```
org.tigris.subversion.javahl.ClientException: RA layer request failed OPTIONS of 'https://XXXXX': could not connect to server (https://XXXX)
```

Why? My "Netbeans" is configured to use "system" proxy configuration (i don't have any proxy at all). Same error is shown when i tell netbeans not to use proxy. This issue sure has nothing to do with proxy, otherwise "Subclipse" wouldn't work too, right?

Comment: Check your Windows Firewall settings. You're now trying to access the SVN server from another application and you may need to give it permissions to communicate on a certain port, with a certain protocol.

Comment: I have no idea how to do it. I never did it. Can i just turn off Windows firewall completely? Is it of any use in real world or it's something like "windows antivirus" and etc?

Comment: Here you go: http://maximumpcguides.com/windows-7/how-to-manage-the-windows-7-firewall/

Comment: Hmmm thanks but i never worked with network so i have no idea about what port is used for svn, which program is blocked by firewall (if any). I just stopped Windows firewall service and disabled it but no luck. Still can't connect :\

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have turned off firewall, restarted my computer and it worked! Strange...
Thank you, anyway! :)

Answer (score 0):

- What version of NB do you use?
- Make shure SVN client (1.7 in NB 7.2)
  and server have same version.
- Is your link correct? Maybe it contains some sepecial characters like `%20` If you use normal HTTP, does this work?
- Check the svn configs of NB (by default here: `C:\Users\[you]\AppData\Roaming\NetBeans\7.2\config\svn\config` for NB 7.2)
- Take a look at NB logs (`..\AppData\Roaming\NetBeans\7.2\var\log`)
- `Tools -> Options -> Miscellaneous -> Versioning -> Subversion` what is set as client there?
- Did you set a certificate in the checkout window? For problems with certificates see the workaround [here](http://www.toedter.com/blog/?p=9) and [here](http://wiki.netbeans.org/FaqSslUserCert)